# How to convert one enum to another enum in java?

Tags: java, enums

I have;

```
public enum Detailed {
    PASSED, INPROCESS, ERROR1, ERROR2, ERROR3;
}
```

and need to convert it to the following;

```
public enum Simple {
    DONE, RUNNING, ERROR;
}
```

So first `PASSED`->`DONE` and `INPROCESS`->`RUNNING`, but all errors should be: `ERROR`. Obviously it is possible to write cases for all values, but there may be a better solution?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

One way is to define a method `asSimple()` in your `Detailed` enum:

```
public enum Detailed {
    PASSED {
        @Override
        Simple asSimple() {
            return DONE;
        }
    },
    INPROCESS {
        @Override
        Simple asSimple() {
            return RUNNING;
        }
    },
    ERROR1,
    ERROR2,
    ERROR3;
    public Simple asSimple() {
        return Simple.ERROR; // default mapping
    }
}
```

You can then simply call the method when you want to do the mapping:

```
Detailed code = . . .
Simple simpleCode = code.asSimple();
```

It has the advantage of putting the knowledge of the mapping with the `Detailed` enum (where perhaps it belongs). It has the disadvantage of having knowledge of `Simple` mixed in with the code for `Detailed`. This may or may not be a bad thing, depending on your system architecture.

Comment: I think that putting mapping logic within an enum to another enum is breaking encapsulation, introducing coupling and reducing cohesiveness. The concern of an enum should be simply to represent a set of states (or concepts). The concern of mapping from one enum to another should be encapsulated separately.

Comment: @Chomeh - I did note in my answer that `Detailed` would end up requiring knowledge of `Simple`. (Basically, I was expressing the same concern you did in your comment, but with the rather vague critique of calling it a "disadvantage". You were much more precise.) Nevertheless, I think this approach is worth considering. OP's enum names suggests that `Detailed` is conceptually a refinement of `Simple`. If that's the case, then it's not a bad thing at all that `Detailed` is coupled to `Simple` (much as it's not always bad that a subclass is coupled to its parent class).

Answer (score 36):

Personally I would just create a `Map<Detailed, Simple>` and do it explicitly - or even use a `switch` statement, potentially.

Another alternative would be to pass the mapping into the constructor - you could only do it one way round, of course:

```
public enum Detailed {
    PASSED(Simple.DONE),
    INPROCESS(Simple.RUNNING),
    ERROR1(Simple.ERROR),
    ERROR2(Simple.ERROR),
    ERROR3(Simple.ERROR);

    private final Simple simple;

    private Detailed(Simple simple) {
        this.simple = simple;
    }

    public Simple toSimple() {
        return simple;
    }
}
```

(I find this simpler than Ted's approach of using polymorphism, as we're not really trying to provide different *behaviour* - just a different simple mapping.)

While you *could* potentially do something cunning with the ordinal value, it would be much less obvious, and take more code - I don't think there'd be any benefit.

Comment: This is cleaner IMO, now if you need the mapping in multiple places the Enum itself provides it.

Answer (score 11):

Use [EnumMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html)

I decouple my external xml interface from my internal domain model by implementing a transformation service. This includes mapping enums from jaxb generated code to domain model enums.

Using a static EnumMap encapsulates the concern of transformation within the class responsible for transformation. Its cohesive.

```
@Service
public class XmlTransformer {

    private static final Map<demo.xml.Sense, Constraint.Sense> xmlSenseToSense;
    static {
        xmlSenseToSense = new EnumMap<demo.xml.Sense, Constraint.Sense> (
            demo.xml.Sense.class);
        xmlSenseToSense.put(demo.xml.planningInterval.Sense.EQUALS, 
            Constraint.Sense.EQUALS);
        xmlSenseToSense.put(demo.xml.planningInterval.Sense.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUALS, 
            Constraint.Sense.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUALS);
        xmlSenseToSense.put(demo.xml.planningInterval.Sense.LESS_THAN_OR_EQUALS, 
            Constraint.Sense.LESS_THAN_OR_EQUALS);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Guava's `Enums.getIfPresent()` on `Enum.name()`

Our case was a particular specialization of this one. We do have two `Enum`: one we use in the application and another one we use in the core library. The core library is used by a handful of applications, by different teams. Each application views a subset of the whole functionality. The whole functionality is configured with the enums in order to switch on and off, throttle up or down, select strategies, etc.

So we ended up with:

1. one enum for the library, containing all the possible configurations, visible from the applications and also some library-specific
2. one enum for each application, containing the literals corresponding to what the application can see/touch in the library, and some application-specific

Then as we pass data down to the library, we adapt all data and also those configurations. We own all enums, so we can choose to call the same configuration with the same literal in different enums.

```
Enum LibraryConfig {
    FUNCTION_ONE,
    FUNCTION_TWO,
    FUNCTION_THREE,
    FUNCTION_FOUR;
}

Enum Aplication1Config {
    FUNCTION_ONE,
    FUNCTION_TWO,
    FUNCTION_THREE,
    APPL1_FUNCTION_ONE,
    APPL1_FUNCTION_TWO;
}

Enum Aplication2Config {
    FUNCTION_ONE,
    FUNCTION_TWO,
    FUNCTION_FOUR;
    APPL2_FUNCTION_ONE;
}
```

When we need to convert from one type to another (app --> lib or lib --> app) we use the `getIfPresent()` method from `com.google.common.base.Enums` in this way:

```
Aplication1Config config1App1 = FUNCTION_TWO;
LibraryConfig configLib = Enums.getIfPresent(LibraryConfig.class, config1App1.name()).orNull();
```

We check `configLib` for `null` value to see if there was successful conversion. This last step we use because of the APPX_FUNCTION_YYY, which are application-specific, *and* for the conversion on the direction lib --> app, not to pass configuration values library-specific (`FUNCTION_FOUR` in the example).

### maven's dependency management:

Just in case anyone needs it:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>20.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

### Home grown version:

You can make your own conversion using the Enum methods, but you have to take care of the exception to detect when the conversion did not succeed:

```
try {
    Aplication1Config config1App1 = FUNCTION_TWO;
    LibraryConfig configLib = LibraryConfig.valueOf(config1App1.name());
} catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
    // if the conversion did not succeed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ted's answer is very Javaly, but the expression

```
passed == PASSED ? DONE : ERROR
```

would do the job, too.

Comment: What happened to the INPROCESS -> RUNNING part of the map?

Comment: @Ted: of course you're right, thanks for the correction. I won't propose ``PASSED ? DONE : INPROCESS ? RUNNING : ERROR`` since that is, obviously, less readable. (Then again, I have seen that before, and with good formatting, it [does not look too strange](http://rors.org/2008/01/20/nested-ternary-operator)...)

Comment: @manuelvigarcia - What link? Or should your comment have been addressed to tiwo?

Comment: @tiwo the link does not work. You might want to find another site showcasing the good formatting... I was interested in this solution

Answer (score 0):

To me that sounds more like a conceptual problem than a programming problem. Why don't you just remove the "Simple" enum type and use the other one instead in all places in the program?

Just to make that more clear with another example: Would you really try to define an enum type for the work days in a week (Monday to Friday) and another enum for all days of a week (Monday to Sunday)?

Comment: Since `enum` types cannot inherit from other `enum` types in Java, you're pretty much stuck with doing this kind mapping from time to time.

Comment: I can think of an application --administration-- where you want the next day to be Monday --next banking day-- in some cases and Saturday --next "natural" day-- in others. For example: dealing appointments for teller attention would need the banking days, but when counting vacation days, you count natural days. Once established, the need to align them some time is not unthinkable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple enum mapper with test:

-- IMPLEMENTATION

-- ENUMS

```
public enum FirstEnum {

A(0), B(1);

private final int value;

private FirstEnum(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}
}

public enum  SecondEnum {

C(0), D(1);

private final int valueId;

private SecondEnum(int valueId) {
    this.valueId = valueId;
}

public int getValueId() {
    return valueId;
}

}
```

--MAPPER

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate;

import com.google.common.collect.Sets;

public class EnumPropertyMapping {

private final Map<?, ?> firstMap;
private final Map<?, ?> secondMap;

private final Class<?> firstType;
private final Class<?> secondType;

private EnumPropertyMapping(
        Map<?, ?> firstMap, Map<?, ?> secondMap, Class<?> firstType, Class<?> secondType) {

    this.firstMap = firstMap;
    this.secondMap = secondMap;
    this.firstType = firstType;
    this.secondType = secondType;
}

public static Builder builder() {
    return new Builder();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <R> R getCorrespondingEnum(Object mappedEnum) {
    Validate.notNull(mappedEnum, "Enum must not be NULL");
    Validate.isInstanceOf(Enum.class, mappedEnum, "Parameter must be an Enum");

    if (firstType.equals(mappedEnum.getClass())) {
        return (R) firstMap.get(mappedEnum);
    }

    if (secondType.equals(mappedEnum.getClass())) {
        return (R) secondMap.get(mappedEnum);
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Didn't found mapping for enum value: " + mappedEnum);
}

public static class Builder {

    private final Map<Object, Object> firstEnumMap = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<Object, Object> secondEnumMap = new HashMap<>();
    private Class<?> firstEnumType;
    private Class<?> secondEnumType;

    public <T extends Enum<T>> Builder addFirst(Class<T> enumType, String propertyName) {
        firstEnumType = enumType;
        initMap(firstEnumMap, enumType.getEnumConstants(), propertyName);
        return this;
    }

    public <T extends Enum<T>> Builder addSecond(Class<T> enumType, String propertyName) {
        secondEnumType = enumType;
        initMap(secondEnumMap, enumType.getEnumConstants(), propertyName);
        return this;
    }

    private void initMap(Map<Object, Object> enumMap, Object[] enumConstants, String propertyName) {
        try {
            for (Object constant : enumConstants) {
                enumMap.put(PropertyUtils.getProperty(constant, propertyName), constant);
            }
        } catch (InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
    }

    public EnumPropertyMapping mapEnums() {
        Validate.isTrue(firstEnumMap.size() == secondEnumMap.size());
        Validate.isTrue(Sets.difference(firstEnumMap.keySet(), secondEnumMap.keySet()).isEmpty());

        Map<Object, Object> mapA = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Object, Object> mapB = new HashMap<>();

        for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> obj : firstEnumMap.entrySet()) {
            Object secondMapVal = secondEnumMap.get(obj.getKey());
            mapA.put(obj.getValue(), secondMapVal);
            mapB.put(secondMapVal, obj.getValue());
        }
        return new EnumPropertyMapping(mapA, mapB, firstEnumType, secondEnumType);
    }
}

}
```

-- TEST

```
import org.junit.Test;

import com.bondarenko.common.utils.lang.enums.FirstEnum;
import com.bondarenko.common.utils.lang.enums.SecondEnum;

import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals;

public class EnumPropertyMappingTest {

@Test
public void testGetMappedEnum() {
    EnumPropertyMapping mapping = EnumPropertyMapping.builder()
                                                                                                     .addSecond(SecondEnum.class, "valueId")
                                                                                                     .addFirst(FirstEnum.class, "value")
                                                                                                     .mapEnums();

    assertEquals(SecondEnum.D, mapping.getCorrespondingEnum(FirstEnum.B));
    assertEquals(FirstEnum.A, mapping.getCorrespondingEnum(SecondEnum.C));
}

}
```